# AWS-CLI S3: Can list but cannot copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Please help. I have gone through many SO and AWS posts and no solutions seem to be working for me.

I am trying to run the command `aws s3 cp s3://buckets/<bucket-name>/<grandparent-dir>/<parent-dir>/<child-dir> <local-dir> --recursive` in order to copy all the contents of the child-dir folder to a local-dir folder on my machine. I keep getting the error `fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`.

running `aws s3 ls <bucket-name>/<grandparent-dir>/<parent-dir>/<child-dir>` succesfully prints al the items in the child-dir, so I must have ListObjects permissions.

- I am the owner of this bucket. The **id** printed when running `aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID` matches the **id** shown when running `aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket-name> --prefix "<grandparent-dir>/<parent-dir>/<child-dir>"`
- I am logged in as an **IAM User** within the user group **groupA**
- **groupA** has the following **IAM** policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

- The bucket itself has the followoing bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1546414473940",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1546414471931",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<user-id>:user/<user-name>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

- I have run `aws configure` and put in my valid **access_key**, **secret_key**, and **region**. I have confirmed this with `aws configure list` as well as opening the `/.aws/credentials` file. The region selected is the same as the region of the bucket.
- I have logged in as the root user and turned all 4 options off for **Block Public Access** both in the permissions tab of the **bucket** itself and the **account** options on the left side menu.

Still, after all this, I am getting the error `fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied` when trying to run the copy command. However, the list command is working.

What am I doing wrong? Please save me!

If I have left any important information out, please let me know.

Comment: Well, I think the error is clear, you are missing `ListObjectsV2` on both side (user permission and bucket policy). But, looking at the bucket policy, you won't be able to get an object since the GetObject is not listed here.

Comment: @AnthonyB. `ListObjectsV2` is the name of an API call, but it uses the permission called `ListBucket`.

Comment: @Waleed First, let's test the ability to use access an object using `GetObject`. If you try to download an object from the bucket using `aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/<filename> <local-dir>`, does it work successfully?

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein. Thank you for the response. If I put the command `aws s3 cp s3://buckets/<bucket-name>/<grandparent-dir>/<parent-dir>/<child-dir>/<filename> <local-dir>` without the --recursive tag, I get the error *fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden*. If I add the --recursive tag i get the same ListObjectsV2 error as before. Does that provide any hints to the problem?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you are a king among men my friend. After reading your post and noticing that you did noy start your endpoint with //buckets, but instead with //bucket-name, I made this same modification and now everything works as intended. You are a life savor. Thank you!

Comment: Ah! I should have noticed that too! Feel free to add an Answer to your own Question or, if you don't think it will help future readers because it was just a typing error, feel free to delete the Question.

Comment: I will add an answer just incase someone makes the same mistake in the future. Will mention your comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comment by @JohnRotenstein, I realized that when entering the endpoint name for the s3 bucket, the *buckets* term should not be present. By modifying my endpoint

from:
aws s3 cp **s3://buckets/<bucket-name>/**<grandparent-dir>/<parent-dir>/<child-dir> <local-dir> --recursive

to:
aws s3 cp **s3://<bucket-name>/**<grandparent-dir>/<parent-dir>/<child-dir> <local-dir> --recursive

the download started working.

Huge thank you to @JohnRotenstein!